# Get all forms stored in hubspot as a Dictionary<Guid, object>()

Tags: c#, hubspot

Is it somehow via the Hubspot form api to get all forms in a particular format.

According to the documentation and the preview what it seem to be returning is a list of json objects.

https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/v2/get_forms

Is it somehow possible to alter this format in someway via the api?

I would very likely have it returned as a dictionary, where the key of each entry is the guid, and value is the form itself.

The only way I see its possible is by postprocessing the received input, and then map it into a dictionary, but that seems a bit redundant if it was possible via the api?

Comment: How are you making this API call, does HubSpot provide a client?

Comment: We call hubspot via their api @LarryDukek

Comment: Do you mean via their API client?  I believe they have a REST API, which would have endpoints you would send your calls to, your code would send those calls via some sort of http client.  Many professional services, such as HubSpot, will provide a client for their users.  These clients generally have predefined objects that are returned.  You do have other options, such as the .NET HttpClient and many others.  With HttpClient you would receive the JSON and deserialize that into your defined objects.  I can type up an answer that could help if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Using NewtonSoft's JsonConvert and JsonPropertyAttributes to deserialize the JSON:

Create classes with the properties you need using the JsonPropertyAttribute... something like this:

```
public class FormObj
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "portalId")]
    public int PortalId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "guid")]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cssClass")]
    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "redirect")]
    public string Redirect { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "submitText")]
    public string SubmitText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "followUpId")]
    public string FollowUpId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "notifyRecipients")]
    public string NotifyRecipients { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "leadNurturingCampaignId")]
    public string LeadNurturingCampaignId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "createdAt")]
    public long CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "updatedAt")]
    public long UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "performableHtml")]
    public string PerformableHtml { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "migratedFrom")]
    public string MigratedFrom { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ignoreCurrentValues")]
    public bool IgnoreCurrentValues { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "formFieldGroups")]
    public FormFieldGroup[] FormFieldGroups { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "metaData")]
    public MetaData[] MetaData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deletable")]
    public bool IsDeletable { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "inlineMessage")]
    public string InlineMessage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tmsId")]
    public string? tmsId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "captchaEnabled")]
    public bool IsCaptchaEnabled { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "campaignGuid")]
    public string CampaignGuid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cloneable")]
    public bool IsCloneable { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "editable")]
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "formType")]
    public string FormType { get; set; }
}

public class FormFieldGroup
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fields")]
    public IEnumerable<Field> Fields { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class Field
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "label")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class MetaData
{
    // ...
}
```

The FormFieldGroup, Field and MetaData objects aren't complete, hopefully you can extrapolate the needed properties from the examples.  You can name your properties as you would like, you only need to the JsonPropertyAttribute's PropertyName to match the property in the JSON.  You also do not have to have every property in the JSON in your objects, you have full control.

It is fairly straight forward to deserialize into an IEnumerable of your FormObj and then convert that to your dictionary.

```
var formDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<FormObj>>(JSON).ToDictionary(v => v.Guid);
```

With all that said, creating your own client might look something like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourNamespaceHere
{
    public static class HubSpotClient
    {
        private static Uri baseUri = new Uri(@"https://api.hubapi.com");

        public static async Task<IDictionary<Guid, FormObj>> GetForms()
        {
            var forms = await Get<IEnumerable<FormObj>>(@"/forms/v2/forms?hapikey=demo");
            return forms.ToDictionary(f => f.Guid);
        }

        private static async Task<T> Get<T>(string relativePath)
        {
            var json = await CallHubspot(relativePath);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }

        private static async Task<string> CallHubspot(string relativePath)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = baseUri;
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(relativePath);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException e)
                {
                    // add logging or better error handling
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does hubspot not maintain a model, I am bit hessistant om making a custoim model in case it becomes outdated.

Comment: It is normal practice for companies, such as HubSpot, to utilize a versioning strategy with their APIs.  So when they want introduce changes that would break existing calls, they basically create new endpoints for the new versions.  Then you existing processes can continue to function without issue.  If you wanted to incorporate the new functionality they have added, you would update your code to call the new endpoints as well as the definitions of what you would receive from those calls.

Comment: I would suspect that this how the HubSpot client functions as well.  Their client/models wouldn't dynamically update, you would need to pull the newer version of their client into your code and that newer client would then make its requests to the new (version) endpoint and then return the new model back to you.   Either way you would be updating your code.

Comment: However, if you don't want to use your own model, you would be stuck with the model that HubSpot's client returns.  The question you need to answer, to yourself, is are you okay with the model that HubSpot supplies or would you like to deserialize the response into the model you want to use.  The custom models above merely are an option to avoid being stuck using HubSpot's models or mapping their models into your own after deserialization.